# How to reset the ConditionFirstBoot in systemd?

Tags: linux, boot, systemd

How to make the system think that it's the first boot again?

Need that for some fast testing without reflashing the image.

Comment: Why don't you just temporarily turn it off, then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, in the version that I'm using this option doesn't even exist. This question is a bit useless, I'll delete it if you don't have any other ideas. The problem with some actual context is here: http://serverfault.com/questions/731179/how-to-use-systemd-firstboot-service

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the `/etc/machine-id` file. This will unpopulate the machine and ConditionFirstBoot will be `yes` again.